# get the input box 'name' using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am making form in PHP and submitting using javascript. I want to get the name of input box, As normal coding gives the value of the input box, but i need to get name of input box. Without onclick functionality on it. Can it possible that retrieving the name of input box in other javascript function on click a button.
for example

```
<input type="radio" name="text_name" value="4" id="d">
```

Now onclick a other button I am calling `test()`, In `test()` how can I get the name of the input box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var txtbox = document.getElementById("d");
var txtboxname = txtbox.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

u can do that by using attr function...

in yout test function add this...

```
$('#d').attr('name');  // this will return text_name in your case (if you are using jquery)
```

OR

```
var inputname=document.getElementById("d").name  //javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

put this on your javascript function

```
var name=document.getElementById("d").name;
```

Answer (score 0):

> function test() 
>   {
>    return document.getElementById("d").name; }

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do, but if your script is called from a listener on a button in the form, you can do:

```
<input type="button" value="Send form" onclick="doSubmit(this)">
```

Then the doSubmit function is something like:

```
function doSubmit(el) {
  var form = el.form;
  var control, controls = form.elements;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];

    /*  
        Do stuff with control.
        Control name is control.name, control value is control.value
    */
  }
}
```

I would strongly recommend that your form has a standard submit button and works without any scripting, then you can add your scripted submission to the form's submit handler. It can cancel the standard submit and do its own thing.

That way if script is disabled, not available or fails for some reason, the user can still submit the form.